# The code generated from "pulumi import" lacks a lot of details

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I want to use pulumi to import one of my existing resources on AWS.

So I ran `pulumi import aws:elasticache/cluster:Cluster my-redis my-redis` command and got the following details in the output:

```
= aws:elasticache/cluster:Cluster: (import) 
    [id=my-redis]
    [urn=urn:pulumi:prod::my_aws_infra::aws:elasticache/cluster:Cluster::my-redis]
    [provider=urn:pulumi:prod::my_aws_infra::pulumi:providers:aws::default_4_0_0::5bcb13d1-6ocf-qb30-bf12-6c7a1683a072]
    availabilityZone      : "ap-northeast-1c"
    azMode                : "single-az"
    clusterId             : "my-redis"
    engine                : "redis"
    engineVersion         : "4.0.10"
    maintenanceWindow     : "sat:20:00-sat:21:00"
    nodeType              : "cache.t3.small"
    notificationTopicArn  : "arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:123456789123:redis_sns_topic"
    numCacheNodes         : 1
    parameterGroupName    : "default.redis4.0"
    port                  : 6379
    securityGroupIds      : [
        [0]: "sg-b6d1b86al301zd054"
        [1]: "sg-5yfa3a33"
    ]
    snapshotRetentionLimit: 0
    snapshotWindow        : "16:30-17:30"
    subnetGroupName       : "default"
    tags                  : {
    }
```

The code I get from `pulumi import ...` becomes

```
my_redis = aws.elasticache.Cluster("my-redis",
    cluster_id="my-redis",
    notification_topic_arn="arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:123456789123:redis_sns_topic",
    opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(protect=True))
```

Why does the generated code lack a lot of information (`availabilityZone`, `azMode`, `engine`, etc)?

The code works correctly when I run `pulumi up`.

How does pulumi know all the configurations of the redis resource?

Are the configurations stored in the backend of pulumi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/6856, you can see that one of the developers of pulumi says

> This is the expected behavior. For the purposes of importing the
> resource to be managed by Pulumi, the necessary inputs are specified
> in the code generated. You are of course welcome to include the
> additional details in your code, but Pulumi has generated what is
> necessary to import the resource.
>
> To see all of the inputs/outputs of your resources, you can take a
> look at your state file (`pulumi stack export`).

So this is an expected behavior. The developers of pulumi don't want to show all the details in the code by default.

And currently, there's no way generate a code with all the details.

Those details are stored in the backend of pulumi. They can be found in `.pulumi/stacks/<my-stack>.json` in the backend.